# Как сделать кнопку Edit?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, edit

прошу помощи - как сделать кнопку edit для редактирования строки (я чайник) javascript не понимаю, желательно php если возможно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ссылку на сайт можно?

Comment: Посмотреть как работают другие и сделать так же.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button

Answer (score 0):

Чудеса:

```js
function button_click(){
  alert("Нажата кнопка!");
}
```

```css
.btn, .fc button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-danger {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FF4961;
    border-color: #FF4961;
}
.box-shadow-2 {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled), .fc button:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger box-shadow-2" onclick = "button_click()">Edit</button>
```

Comment: причём тут CSS?

Comment: @Кирилл Эм... так её без css не сделать.

Comment: Так она у меня уже есть, я не знаю как её заставить работать, чтобы по нажатию можно было редактировать поля

Comment: Сайт который я дал - это мой

Comment: @Кирилл так в вопросе сказано как сделать кнопку edit! Ну надо ж было написать клик на edit а не как сделать!

Comment: @Кирилл Все, подправил вам. Тестируйте.

Comment: "как сделать кнопку edit для редактирования строки" + на скрине уже видно что она сделана

Comment: @Кирилл Ну а код дать? Я что, за вас весь сайт должен написать? Дайте мне кнопку(html, css) хотя лучше весь элемент который на картинке. Завтра сделаю.

Comment: Весь сайт уже написан - осталось только редактирование полей в строке, о чём я и попросил помощи

Comment: @Кирилл ну я же должен как-то привести пример.

Comment: @Кирилл вместо того что бы привести в пример код по которому вам можно подсказать и нормально сформулировать вопрос Вы еще и наезжаете на человека который Вам попытался помочь? Интересно...